# Get Incident details such as assigned to, comments by the analyst,Incident ID etc using query in Logs

Tags: azure-sentinel

I am investigating incidents but I need to tie them with the **SOC analyst who worked on it and what comments were added** by them. I am not able to find these details in any table. 
This will be helpful to pull out the metrics for the SOC team.
Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Understandably, these are difficult to expose right now. They are located in the AzureActivity table (with the Azure Activity Data Connector enabled).

We will be making this much easier very soon with a new table specific to Incidents.

In the interim, here's a KQL snippet that you can use to start sifting through the results for Incidents in the AzureActivity table:

AzureActivity
| where _ResourceId has "Microsoft.SecurityInsights" and _ResourceId has "incidents"

Comment: Thank you! It isn't perfect but a good workaround for now. Waiting for the fix!